# tengo una tabla en html, estatica, quiero darle funcionalidad con javascript, pero no se como

Tags: javascript, html

apenas estoy dand pequeños pasos en programacion, y ahortia estoy haciendo una tabla que me seria util en mi trabajo, ya la tengo en HTML muy simple, pero necesito darle la funcion, necestio que insertando una tasa porcentual, la dividad por diferentes valores y los organize en los espacios de la tabla, les dejo una foto para que se hagan una idea, cualquier asesoria seria muy bien recibida, gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve en la imagen seria que cada monto dividido por la tasa porcentual, se posicione en su respectivo lugar del lado donde dice bolivares

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos lo que intentastes? Y el codigo va como texto (En este caso, la tabla)

Comment: Hola @kelvin. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Además, puede consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas aumentar tus posibilidades de obtener ayuda. También, puede consultar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ten presente que debes proporcionar el código que ha formado la tabla que nos compartes acá en forma de imagen.

Answer (score 1):

no entiendo muy buen a que te refieres... pero si lo que quieres es que cambien los resultados de la parte de al lado deberas incluir codigo de javascript en tu pagina para poder hacerlo... algo asi:

```js
function calcular_valores() {
  var tasa = document.getElementById("tasa").value;

  var val1 = 20;
  var val2 = 30;
  
  var val1convertido = val1 / tasa;
  var val2convertido = val2 / tasa;
  
  document.getElementById("1izq").innerHTML = val1;
  document.getElementById("1der").innerHTML = val1convertido.toFixed(2);
  
  document.getElementById("2izq").innerHTML = val2;
  document.getElementById("2der").innerHTML = val2convertido.toFixed(2);

  
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        Introduce tasa de conversion: <input type="number" id="tasa" value="0.001988">       
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button onclick="calcular_valores()">Calcular</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor Original<br> (Pesos)</td>
    <td>Valor En bolivares</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="1izq">20.00</label>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="1der">0.00</label>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="2izq">30.00</label>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="2der">0.00</label>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

de cualquier manera yo no soy una experta... entonces yo te recomendaria que investigaras un poco mas al menos que hicieras el diseño de la tabla con codigo html y luego preguntaras como hacerlo para que alguien que si sepa bien te diga como, saludos.

lo que hice fue la tabla con un boton que llama a una funcion en javascript la cual genera los resultados en base al valor que le hayas introducido